# Accessing view manager configs directly off UIManager via UIManager['getConstants'] is no longer supported

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have installed react-navigation react-navigation react-native-gesture-handler i am using expo to run the app on an xcode simulator

```
Accessing view manager configs directly off UIManager via UIManager['getConstants'] is no longer supported. Use UIManager.getViewManagerConfig('getConstants') instead.
- node_modules/expo/build/environment/muteWarnings.fx.js:17:23 in warn
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/UIManager.js:164:12 in get
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Utilities/defineLazyObjectProperty.js:42:18 in getValue
- node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/createHandler.js:39:2 in <unknown>
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
- node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/NativeViewGestureHandler.js:3:0 in <unknown>
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
- node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/createNativeWrapper.js:3:0 in <unknown>
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
- node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/GestureHandler.js:1:0 in <unknown>
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
- node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable.js:10:0 in <unknown>
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
- node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/index.js:1:0 in <unknown>
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
- node_modules/react-navigation-stack/lib/module/views/StackView/StackViewLayout.js:1:942 in <unknown>
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
- node_modules/react-navigation-stack/lib/module/views/StackView/StackView.js:1:670 in <unknown>
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
- node_modules/react-navigation-stack/lib/module/navigators/createStackNavigator.js:1:122 in <unknown>
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
- node_modules/react-navigation-stack/lib/module/index.js:1:35 in <unknown>
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
* App.js:4:0 in <unknown>
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
- node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js:4:0 in <unknown>
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:197:45 in guardedLoadModule
* null:null in global code
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure it is:

**"react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.3.0"**

1- check package.json has '~' instead of '^' before version number.

2- remove node_modules folder and package-lock.json file

3- do npm install

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using expo, you can now use the command

```
expo install react-native-gesture-handler
```

This will make sure nothing breaks by installing `react-native-gesture-handler` in version 1.3.0 instead of 1.5.x.
There is a [pretty recent issue on Github](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/742) discussing this.